# Bootstrap Nav Bar JQuery Partially Fixed

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

So I have a template that all the pages on my site are created from. Here's an example of what I want: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9TMnJ/1/)

However, on my site, since those links go to a specific page (i.e About.html when you click the about link), that page loads the html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="masthead">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What happens is:
1) I click the about link in the nav bar
2) Page directs to About.html
3) Navbar highlights the About link for a second (executing that jquery code)
4) When the page loads, Home becomes the active class again because of `<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>`

So essentially the link you click highlights for a second and then home gets highlighted again. How do I make it work like in fiddle (where the links stays highlighted in the navbar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the default li.active from the html, so replace your following line:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

for this one:

```
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

Then set the active li when the page loads by looking at the url, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav li a').click(function (e) {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    }).each(function() {
        if ( location.href.indexOf('about.html') && $(this).text() == 'About') {
             $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        } else if (location.href.indexOf('calendar.html') && $(this).text() == 'Calendar') {
             $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```